# Ethernet header's configuration of a RAW packet in C

Tags: c

I have two virtual machines in vmware workstation with Ubuntu 22.04. I can see the raw packet in Wireshark but the configuration of the ether header is not what I expect. I want the following format: DESTINATIONMAC SOURCEMAC LENGHTOFPACKET TEXT. I don't now why, but I can't write the DESTINATIONMAC correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/filter.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int s, stat;
    ssize_t cc;
    unsigned char buf[ETH_FRAME_LEN];
    struct sockaddr_ll saddr = {};
    struct ifreq ifopts;    // for promiscuous mode 
    struct ifreq ifr = {};
    const char *interface = "enp2s1";

    s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    if (s < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // Set Promiscuous Mode
    strncpy(ifopts.ifr_name, interface, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    ioctl(s, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifopts);
    ifopts.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
    ioctl(s, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifopts);

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, interface, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if (ioctl(s, SIOGIFINDEX, &ifr)) {
        perror("ioctl");
        close(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Source MAC address
    saddr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    saddr.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    saddr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
    saddr.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
    unsigned char src_mac[ETH_ALEN] = {0x00, 0x0d, 0x16, 0xb8, 0x36, 0x99};
    memcpy(saddr.sll_addr, src_mac, ETH_ALEN);

    stat = fcntl(s, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if (stat < 0)
        perror("bloqueante");

    const char *message = "Hello World";
    size_t message_len = strlen(message);

    struct sockaddr_ll daddr = {};
    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *)buf;

    // Destination MAC address
    daddr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    daddr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
    daddr.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    daddr.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
    unsigned char dest_mac[ETH_ALEN] = {0x00, 0x0d, 0x29, 0x26, 0xad, 0x98};
    memcpy(daddr.sll_addr, dest_mac, ETH_ALEN);

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&daddr, sizeof(daddr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Prepare Ethernet header
    memcpy(eth->h_dest, daddr.sll_addr, ETH_ALEN);
    memcpy(eth->h_source, saddr.sll_addr, ETH_ALEN);
    eth->h_proto = htons(ETH_P_ALL);

    const char *message2 = "Byebye Moon";
    size_t message_len2 = strlen(message2);

    // Prepare message payload
    memcpy(buf + sizeof(struct ethhdr), message, message_len);
    memcpy(buf + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + message_len, message2, message_len2);

    // Send the packet
    cc = sendto(s, buf, sizeof(struct ethhdr) + message_len + message_len2, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
    if (cc < 0) {
        perror("sendto");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(s);

    return 0;
}
```